# Configure larger font in Jitsi on 3200x1800 resolution on 13 inch display

Tags: resolution, fonts, dpi

### KDE

I installed [Jitsi Chat](https://jitsi.org/Main/DebianNightlyRepository) on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro on Kubuntu.

I already adjusted the main Fonts to 230Dpi in KDE settings, but Jitsi doesent obey this.

How can I enlarge fonts in Jitsi too?

### Unity

On Ubuntu 14.04 it is also a problem: There I [adjusted the overall text-scale-factor to x2.0 with unity-tweak-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/how-to-adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen), and it adjusts the fonts in jitsy as desired, but it doesnt ajust the lineheight of one contact:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 14.04 we have an option that helps a bit:

**Scaling Support**

In the image below we can see the scaling it has at 0.75 on the fonts and title bars:

[image]

Set this to factor 2.0 and revert your text-scale-factor to x1.0 in unity-tweak-tool,

This enhances the Juitsi interface a bit, (but not in all places)