# Adapt Ubuntu to a high-DPI resolution screen

Tags: xorg, fonts, display-resolution, hdpi

How can I adapt Ubuntu to a high resolution display?

I have a display with 3200x1600px on only 11'' and everything looks really tiny.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There are some steps to take:

### 1. System wide Menu and titlebar scaling

**Starting with Ubuntu 14.04** we have an option that helps a bit:

Scaling Support

open the System Settings (here in english:)

```
LANG=c unity-control-center
```

Go to "Displays" and set the "Scale for menu and title bars":

[image: system settings scale system wide]

**Since Ubuntu 17.10** the scaling can be set in

```
LANG=c gnome-control-center
```

Go to `Settings > Devices > Displays` there

see also: [How to find and change the screen DPI?](https://askubuntu.com/a/462023/34298)

### 2. Universal Access

Go to "Universal Access" (`unity-control-center universal-access`) and select "Large Text".
***Note***: not all applications handle this correctly, some will not reserve the extra space, so some UI elements are not accessible with this option!

### 3.increase unity dock size

In `unity-control-center`->`Appearance`->`Look` at the botom, you can adjust the size

### 4. adapt Firefox

see: [Adjust Firefox and Thunderbird to a High DPI touchscreen display (retina)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487032/adjust-firefox-and-thunderbird-to-a-high-dpi-touchscreen-display-retina)

(or use Chrome, which works fine since Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.10, though Chrome will need to be restarted to take effect)

### 5. increase font in Pidgin

There is a plugin you can install

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin-extprefs
```

Then you can increase the font in Plugins->Extended Prefs

### 6. create starter for applications that still don't scale

Some applications still don't obey the global scaling (mainly java) for those few applications you can create a starter to only [Fix scaling of java-based applications for a high DPI screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/change-resolution-while-program-is-running)

---

in older Ubuntu versions, with [unity-tweak-util](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) in the section "Fonts" you can set the "Text Scaling Factor" to 2.0. This will scale the fonts in most applications to double size.

Comment: Is there a way to scale the login menu as well? This is all working perfectly for me on the latest version of Ubuntu, but the login screen looks ridiculously small :(

Comment: Never thought about the urgency to change that as well. But if you find a solution please report it here

Comment: This leaves so many holes. Ubuntu needs to make a concerted effort to consolidate these issues into a proper option for the display settings.

Comment: [You can also scale per-application with `run_scaled`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145216/349837).

Answer (score 10):

Go to System Settings and then to displays. Look for "Scale for menu and title bars." then drag the slider to whatever size you want.

Comment: Cool this works, for a screenshot see: [How to find and change the screen DPI?](http://askubuntu.com/a/462023)

Answer (score 4):

I have a MacBookPro Retina display. The accepted solution partially worked for me but I was unable to get Java apps to work properly, and I found the OS to become too laggy while using 2x scaling.

Changing resolutions while using Ubuntu's default Nouveau display driver would result in a black screen and force me to restart my computer.

I finally found a solution, and a simple one. But this does not use scaling and this will **not take advantage of HiDPI**, but at least **Ubuntu will be usable**.

- Open "System Settings" -> "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers".

  - I selected "Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 from nvidia-352 (proprietary, tested)".
  - Restart computer.
- Launch NVIDIA X Server Settings.

  - Select "X Server Display Configuration"
  - Select the resolution of your choice and enjoy the target resolution full of Ubuntuness (and not a black screen!).

Comment: I should add that I was unable to get the NVIDIA settings to persist correctly. Every time I rebooted the machine the resolution would be wrong. I since bought a refurbished thinkpad to run Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't seem to find any option there to change the resolution though. It displays the current resolution but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows programs using Wine I found the answer via a virtual desktop - (this also avoids the 32-bit page fault error that can happen) - so either run your program from command line thus - or create a shell script for this command -

wine explorer /desktop=d1,3840x2160 Keditw32.exe & disown

This way I'm able to run my favourite windows editor on UHD display with NVidia graphics card just fine.