# icon scaling seems to work partially on a dell 4k display. I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mouse, display, cursor, dpi, scaling

a newbie here.

I'm using a dell 4k display on ubuntu 14.04(up-to-date so far).

I have already followed the instructions on this link - [Adapt Ubuntu to a high-DPI resolution screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen) - it struck me with some awesome hidpi display thanks to all the work put into.

One thing that doesn't work properly though, is the mouse cursor scaling. The scaling seems to work properly 'inside application border' but when I move the pointer outside the border (of that application), i.e., entering to the desktop background (plain background without any windows) the cursor gets rescaled to its original size (half the size in my case). The same thing happens when the cursor moves into any application's titlebar area.

It doesn't seems to find a fix for it easily (or blame my poor googling skill) I could use some of your helps here. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue on Asus ux501. Also, some UI elements like radio button are still tiny.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you no improvement in the situation. But I have an explanation for you. The 4K technology is relatively new. On the other hand your system is relatively old. If you want to improve the situation, then you must use newer software versions. A first step is to update your system to Vivid or to Wily in some days. And then the application developers are required. The individual applications have to be adjusted.

I'm sure, in the coming months, your problem will gradually solve itself.