# How can I make text and icons larger on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: fonts, thinkpad, accessibility

I am using a Thinkpad t460, 14 inch screen. Recently installed Ubuntu on the same. The problem I am facing is that all the text and icons are very small by default. The same issue isn't appearing when using Windows (everything resizes properly).

I've tried accessibility options and increasing font size but nothing works. Any suggestions on how to properly resize the GUI to adapt to the smaller screens?

Comment: This is not ideal, but have you tried changing the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tweak Tool > Fonts** and then increase *Scaling Factor*

[image: Fonts menu in Tweaks]

Comment: This works in increasing the text size of the menu headings etc. but doesn't achieve proper adaptability (still need to zoom in on each tab/application before getting a comfortabl text size). Is there anything else better than this?

Answer (score 1):

In 16.04, there is no need for the Tweak Tool. Scaling is supported out of the box; check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/472266/22471)

I personally have found that going to **System Settings > Displays** and then setting the *Scale for menu and title bars* works for me.