# Ubuntu 17.10 with 1080p laptop screen everything is really small

Tags: gnome, 17.10

i'm using Ubuntu 17.10 xorg and just placed a 1080p panel into my lenovo t440p.  The UI and font is really small and hard to read without zooming.  I tried scaling, but that makes everything slightly blurry.  Everything looks great on my external monitor, how can I properly increase the size of the UI and text on my laptop display?

Comment: I think this thread might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen

Comment: @PhilipZ.  Switching to large text worked for my laptop screen, but it also does it for my external monitor.