# Some tray Icons look weird

Tags: icons, indicator, system-tray, hdpi

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time, and noticed that some icons in tray (appindicator or whatever its called here) are ugly, some are nice:

[image: screenshot]

Any way to fix this?

p.s. using hi-dpi screen, Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Probably those images aren't appropriate for higher resolution displays, and scale all wonky. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/472262/459652 (I don't know if this will fix those icons, as they may be fixed and just scale badly.)

Comment: I would suggest providing your release of Ubuntu, as any descriptive answers may be tailored for a different release to yours and thus be unhelpful to you.