# Apps shown in very tiny windows

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution

i have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and after installing application like CodeBlocks and Zoom i have an issue that the apps are shown in a very tiny windows and icons, i tried different resolution but it does not help, i like how the desktop and everything looks, the problem is only on couple application. I got lenovo yoga 730 with 4k resolution.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adapt Ubuntu to a high-DPI resolution screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen)

Comment: @Zzzach... yes, non of these worked..

Comment: From what I've seen, high DPI is a mixed bag. Unless/until someone else comes with a better answer, you might need to fix these issues on a program-by-program basis. Here's some hints for Zoom and other Qt based applications: https://superuser.com/questions/1381054/how-to-enable-hidpi-support-on-zoom-us-linux-client

Comment: @Zzzach... Thank you worked  !